# Strange error with EXT.NET in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, extjs, aspnet-development-server

I got the exception in my ASP NET MVC APPLICATION developed with ext.net in c#.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________
ItemTag validation (_tkn_7): Reference token     (id22be3fe15600a888_ClientInit) was not found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: ItemTag validation (_tkn_7): Reference token (id22be3fe15600a888_ClientInit) was not found.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Exception: ItemTag validation (_tkn_7): Reference token     (id22be3fe15600a888_ClientInit) was not found.]
Transformer.NET.ItemTag.Validate() +209
Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Handle() +298
Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Transform(List`1 tokensType, Dictionary`2 variables) +32
Ext.Net.ExtNetTransformer.Transform(String text) +554
Ext.Net.InitScriptFilter.Flush() +145
System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +603
System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +121
System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +119
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Comment: Please include the relevant piece(s) of code that cause this error.

Comment: Also, can you post the stack trace ?